# Django is not accepting my nested for loop with double zip

Tags: django, for-loop

In views.py I have:

```
mylist1 = ["peru", "germany", "japan"]
mylist2 = [["lima","cusco"], ["berlin","munich"], ["tokyo"]]
mylist3 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
mylist = zip(mylist1, zip(mylist2, mylist3))
```

In templates

```
for country, info in mylist:
    {{country}}
    for city, number in info:
        {{city}}
        {{number}}
```

error: `Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.`
I feel my double zip definition is not being accepted or properly read. any ideas on how to fix this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to end up with something like this:

```py
# expected result

[
    # (country, [(city, number)])
    ("peru", [("lima", 1), ("cusco", 2)]),
    ("germany", [("berlin", 3), ("munich", 4)]),
    ("japan", [("tokyo", 5)]
]
```

However, the way you're using `zip` here, the end result is completely different than what you expect:

```py
# what you're really getting (unexpected)

[
    ('peru', (['lima', 'cusco'], [1, 2])),
    ('germany', (['berlin', 'munich'], [3, 4])),
    ('japan', (['tokyo'], [5]))
]
```

---

Let's do this using a much more obvious and understandable for-loop:

```py
mylist = []

for country, cities, numbers in zip(mylist1, mylist2, mylist3):
    city_num_pairs = []
    for city, number in zip(cities, numbers):
        city_num_pairs.append((city, number))

    mylist.append((country, city_num_pairs))
```